# Write to /tmp directory in aws lambda with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, errno, tmp

**Goal**

I'm trying to write a zip file to the /tmp folder in a python aws lambda, so I can extract manipulate before zipping, and placing it in s3 bucket.

**Problem**

Os Errno30 Read Only FileSystem

This code was tested locally on my computer to make sure the file would write to my working directory before I uploaded it to aws. This is the code i'm trying to use.

```
file = downloadFile() #This is api call that returns binary zip object
newFile = open('/tmp/myZip.zip','wb')
newFile.write(file)
extractAll('/tmp/myZip.zip')
```

here is the code that is trying to extract the zip file

```
def extractAll(self,source):
        with zipfile.ZipFile(source, 'r') as archive:
            archive.extractall()
```

here is the trace

```
[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/task/test-deploy': OSError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/web.py", line 31, in web
performAction(bb, eventBody)
File "/var/task/src/api/web.py", line 42, in performAction
zipHelper.extractAll('/tmp/myZip.zip')
File "/var/task/src/shared/utils/zipfilehelper.py", line 24, in extractAll
archive.extractall()
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1491, in extractall
self.extract(zipinfo, path, pwd)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1479, in extract
return self._extract_member(member, path, pwd)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1538, in _extract_member
os.mkdir(targetpath)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/task/test-deploy'
```

Comment: In the first line, where are you downloading this file from/to? Lambda has temporary storage only at /tmp. Make sure you are downloading it to /tmp.

Comment: How do you know downloadFile is trying to store in  /tmp/ ?

Comment: downloadFile() is getting a binary object from another api

Comment: I was assuming '/tmp/myZip.zip' the /tmp/  in my destination would resolve to the tmp storage for the lambda

Comment: Please add the full error traceback and the code of `downliadFile()` to your question!

Comment: So actually looks like it is breaking on the extract

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`extractAll()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall) will extract files in the current directory, which is `/var/task/test-deploy` in your case.

You need to use [`os.chdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir) to change the current directory:

```
import os, zipfile

os.chdir('/tmp')
with zipfile.ZipFile(source, 'r') as archive:
    archive.extractall()
```

Even better, you can [create a temporary directory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory) and extract the files there, to avoid polluting `/tmp`:

```
import os, tempfile, zipfile

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
    os.chdir(tmpdir)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(source, 'r') as archive:
        archive.extractall()
```

If you want to restore the current working directory after extracting the file, consider using this decorator:

```
import os, tempfile, zipfile, contextlib

@contextlib.context_manager
def temporary_work_dir():
    old_work_dir = os.getcwd()
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp_dir:
        os.chdir(tmp_dir)
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            os.chdir(old_work_dir)

with temporary_work_dir():
    with zipfile.ZipFile(source, 'r') as archive:
        archive.extractall()
```