# How I can store a temp file on AWS Lambda using NetCore

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need download file into the `/tmp` folder in an AWS Lambda function.

And I need work with this file and get my file route.

Comment: Can you be more explicit? What have you tried? What programming language are you using? What error are you getitng?

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48364250/write-to-tmp-directory-in-aws-lambda-with-python. also note that /tmp directory storage limit is
512 MB.

Answer (score 1):

since you didn't mention language
heres example using Python

```
FILE_NAME = "/tmp/lol.csv"
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
with open('FILE_NAME', 'wb') as f:
    s3.download_fileobj('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', f)
```

[Details here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html)
 And ofcourse similar to boto3 depending on your language you'll get libraries which will facilitate this. e.g [for C#](https://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/s3/csharp/)